# Is an ampersand allowed in a href string?

Tags: html

I'm a bit confused by the results of the html validator at [validator.w3.org/check](http://validator.w3.org/check)

(I am using the `<!DOCTYPE html>` (html 5) option, and the site says that there may be mistakes in the new HTML 5 validator.  I'm not sure whether I am looking at a mistake or not.)

It complains about this line:

```
<a href="itempurchasesell?id=2&purchase=true&loc=Main%20Warehouse">
```

It says: `& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as & amp;.)`

Can I ignore this error, or is something wrong with my code?  Please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: It's not valid to use `&` in href. You should use `&amp;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been told in comments : use `&amp;` (without space between `&` and `amp;`)